# AngularJS get post response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one AngularJS project. it is using as front end, and I have a Java web application as a back end. From AngularJS project, I am redirecting to a URL which is outside of the applications(both Java and AngularJS). From that site, It is processing the request and returning to the AngularJS application, with some data as post.

My Java application runs on

```
http://localhost:8080/myjavaapp
```

AngularJS app runs on

```
http://localhost:8080/myangularapp
```

From AngularJS app, I am redirecting to a some URL

```
http://someotherwebsite.com/somepage?someparam=somevalue
```

After processing the request it sends back to AngularJS project.

```
http://localhost:8080/myangularapp/#/responsepage
```

But that is sending as a Post. And I want to get a request parameter in my AngularJS application. But when I return to the angularJS page, it shows error

**`Cannot POST /`**

If I used a JSP page, I could get the request parameter like

```
String responseString = (String) request.getParameter("response");
```

But its only HTML and JS controlers in AngularJS project. 
Is it possible to send as post? If so, How can I get the post parameter in the JS controller?

**EDIT**

From other site if it's redirecting like

```
http://localhost:8080/myangularapp/#/responsepage?response=somevalue
```

Then it's a GET request, and easily I can get the value of **response** using ***`$routeParams`***. it's like `$http.get("someurl?response=value")`

But in this usecase, It is sending as a POST request. Like `$http.post("someurl")`. Parameters are **POST** and I am not able to get the value. How can I get it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear, can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to use an angular **browser** application like a server application.  Can't you get the Java application to talk to the other application?  Does the other application support JSONP?  If so is there a payload you can send from the ng app and get the response back. AFAIK you can't post to a browser, so the architecture sounds wrong.  There are too many question to answer this question but I couldn't put all this in a comment.  Could you use this:

```
$http.jsonp('http://someotherwebsite.com/somepage?someparam=somevalue');
```

You are not post to the server you're using a GET (Querystring) and this will give you the other apps payload.

hope this helps